# Assigning an Object to the .GlobalEnv in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am relatively new to RShiny so I am sorry in advance if this is something that has been elaborated already. My question is simple - if I assign an object `x`, within the server function of RShiny to the global environment via code such as

`assign("x", x, envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Will all users independently accessing the app at the same time be seeing the same copy of the object `x`? Or, is the global environment as declared by the code above still going to be "local" for each session?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `x <<- x` would make `x` visible to all users in less code, not sure about `assign`

Comment: You can read about shiny scoping rules here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html. In theory values in the global scope are shared across uses are long as your shiny server is using just one process.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks. Is there an option to have session-specific global environments in shiny? That is pretty much what I need to have for my code.

Comment: Session specific variables should be enclosed in your `server()` function.